# how to install "Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012" without "Web Platform Installer"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2012

I have visual studio 2012 ultimate for practice , now I want to do SharePoint 2013 development through that. Generally I should download "Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012" through Web Platform Installer, but for some reason I want to avoid installing "Web Platform Installer".

Is there any way where I can download and install "Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012" without downloading "Web Platform Installer"?

Waiting to be guided by you.

Answer (score 0):

Well It seems you can do it in offline mode(still uses WPI in some way).It is possible to download the files for offline install using WebPI so that you can transfer the files in a USB and install it in your server.

http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/downloading-office-developer-tools-for-offline-install-2/

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-v4-command-line-webpicmdexe-rtw-release